# layout real estate android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have several view components in a layout. most of them have visibility=gone and they are turned on only based on certain conditions and this is done programatically.
All of this works fine but even though visibility=gone, there is a blank space occupying that area. how do i remove that>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout android:weightSum="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/subheader_gradient" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/_searchLayout">
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/_search"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_margin="10dp"
        style="@style/formValue" android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword|textCapCharacters"
        android:autoText="false" android:lines="1"
        android:hint="@string/_Text_searchBy" android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColorHint="@color/light_gray" android:textScaleX="1"
        android:textSize="7pt" />
</LinearLayout>


<TextView style="@style/SubHeaderText" android:text="@string/_Heading_searchResults"
    android:id="@+id/_HeadingsearchResults"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/subheader_gradient" android:visibility="gone"></TextView>


<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" android:id="@+id/_HeadingsearchResultsNull"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/_Text_noSymbolsFounds"
    android:textColor="@color/light_gray" style="@style/formLabel"
    android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="@color/white" />
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/_progressLayout" android:background="@color/white"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <ProgressBar style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left" android:id="@+id/_progress"
        android:padding="5dip"></ProgressBar>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/_progressText"
        android:text="@string/_Heading_searching"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:padding="5dip"
        android:textColor="@color/black" android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView android:fadeScrollbars="true" android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/_searchSymbol_list" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:visibility="gone"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" android:background="@color/white"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/white" />

<TextView style="@style/SubHeaderText" android:text="@string/_Heading_recentResults"
    android:id="@+id/_recentResults" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/subheader_gradient"></TextView>


<ListView android:fadeScrollbars="true" android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/_recentQuotes_list" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" android:background="@color/white"
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/white" />
```

[image: Space right above recent results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send your layout XML. Or if you want to identify, which layout is causing problems, set different background color for each one and then you can try different parameters for layout size.

Comment: Are you not missong a LinearLayout with vertical orientation on the top of your layout hierarchy?

Comment: I had to use View.Gone and not View.Invisible